# Error de método no soportado al aplicar funcion validate de laravel

Tags: laravel, blade

Estoy creando un proyecto en Laravel 8, pero al tratar de actualizar un cliente en la base de datos me sale el error de The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST. He buscado una solución a este error y he visto que es común, pero he probado algundas de las soluciones que dan y me sigue saliendo. Lo extraño es que el error sale cuando incluyo el médoto validate de laravel, pues cuando quito la validación si me actualiza sin problema:

Esta es la función que llamo del controlador:

```
function update_tercero(Request $request, $codigounicotercero)//Permite actualizar un tercero
{
    $request->validate([//Validar los campos  enviados por la vista
        'ca100PrimerNombre' => 'required',//Validar que el campo este diligenciado
        'ca100PrimerApellido' => 'required',//Validar que el campo este diligenciado
    ]);

    $tercero = Tb100terceroModel::find($codigounicotercero);//Se busca el tercero en la base de datos $tercero->ca100PrimerNombre = $request->ca100PrimerNombre;
            $tercero->ca100PrimerApellido= $request->ca100PrimerApellido; 
            $tercero->save() }
```

Este es mi formulario en la vista

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('tercero.update',$tb100tercero->ca100CodigoUnico)}}" name="formulario">
        @csrf
        @method('PUT')
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                <label for="primernombre">{{ __('Primer Nombre') }}</label>
                                <input id="ca100PrimerNombre" type="text"
                                    class="form-control @error('ca100PrimerNombre') is-invalid @enderror"
                                    name="ca100PrimerNombre" value="{{$tb100tercero->ca100PrimerNombre}}"
                                    autocomplete="ca100PrimerNombre" autofocus placeholder="Primer nombre">
                                @error('ca100PrimerNombre')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>

<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                <label for="primerapellido">{{ __('Primer Apellido') }}</label>
                                <input id="ca100PrimerApellido" type="text"
                                    class="form-control @error('ca100PrimerApellido') is-invalid @enderror"
                                    name="ca100PrimerApellido" value="{{$tb100tercero->ca100PrimerApellido}}"
                                    autocomplete="ca100PrimerApellido" autofocus placeholder="Primer Apellido">
                                @error('ca100PrimerApellido')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
<div class="form-group row  justify-content-center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        {{ __('Guardar') }}
    </button>
</div>
```

Esta es la ruta

```
Route::put('tercero\{codigounicotercero}update_tercero',[TerceroController::class,'update_tercero'])->name('tercero.update');
```

Answer (score 0):

Las url de las rutas deben ir con "/" y creo que te hace falta uno, después del parámetro **codigounicotercero**

```
Route::put('tercero/{codigounicotercero}/update_tercero',[TerceroController::class,'update_tercero'])->name('tercero.update');
```

Comment: Gracias Juan David por tu respuesta, lo modifiqué como me indicas, pero me sigue saliendo el error

Comment: Estas importando correctamente el request en el controlador. 

use Illuminate\Http\Request;